# Under what conditions this function has a fixed point?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

I wanted to know that what is the condition under which the function of the type 
$$k:L^2([a, b]:\mathbb{R}^n)\times L^2([a, b]:\mathbb{R}^m)\rightarrow L^2([a, b]:\mathbb{R}^n)\times L^2([a, b]:\mathbb{R}^m)$$ has a fixed point?

Comment: It might be helpful for the people looking to answer this to understand the motivation of why you are asking this question and the notation you are using here.

Comment: The motivation is this problem is arising in the controllability of a nonlinear systems